# Why is $(document).ready() function not working in my Blazor Server App?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blazor

I want to adapt [this HTML code for the calibration](https://github.com/brownhci/WebGazer/blob/master/www/calibration.html) of [this webgazer for eye tracking](https://github.com/brownhci/WebGazer) for my **Blazor Server App**. But when starting the app, the **$(document).ready(function()** - that should be called from calibration.js - won't start.

The razor component, where I want to implement it, looks like this:

```
@page "/Calibration"

@inject IJSRuntime JS

<h1>Calibration</h1>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">

    <li id="Accuracy"><a>Not yet Calibrated</a></li>

    <li> <button @onclick="CalibrateWebgazer">Calibrate WebGazer</button></li>

</ul>


 <div class="calibrationDiv">
    <button class="Calibration" id="Pt1"></button>
    <button class="Calibration" id="Pt2"></button>
    <button class="Calibration" id="Pt3"></button>
    <button class="Calibration" id="Pt4"></button>
    <button class="Calibration" id="Pt5"></button>
    <button class="Calibration" id="Pt6"></button>
    <button class="Calibration" id="Pt7"></button>
    <button class="Calibration" id="Pt8"></button>
    <button class="Calibration" id="Pt9"></button>

</div>

@code {
    private async Task CalibrateWebgazer()

    {

        await JS.InvokeAsync<object>("Restart");

    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync() => await this.DisposeAsync();
}
```

I placed all the javascript files in a wwwroot/js folder and added their script tag in the _Layout.cshtml file:

```
`<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/webgazer.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/gaze.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/calibration.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/precision_calculation.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/precision_store_points.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/resize_canvas.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>`
```

When clicking on the calibration button, the functions defined in **$(document).ready(function()** are not executed.

What do I need to change to make this work? And how and when does this **$(document).ready(function()** get called? In the [provided HTML example](https://github.com/brownhci/WebGazer/blob/master/www/calibration.html) only the **Restart** function from **main.js** is called - why should the **$(document).ready(function()** from **calibration.js** fire in that case or have I missed something? As I'm very new to programming, I highliy appreciate explanations, why this doesn't work.

Comment: Call `$(document).ready` in a script tag before the closing body tag. That's the safest place where everything is loaded. I usually move scripts to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank's for the suggestion, I put it in the script tag in the _Layout.cshtml just before the closing body tag, but unfortunately, it still doesn't work: `<script>$(document).ready</script>`

Comment: That would probably just output an error - does the browser console contain any errors? It's more like `$(document).ready(function(){ console.log("document ready was called"); });`. Try `jQuery` instead of `$` sometimes that's needed. But check the console messages first.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's see. I haven't read the docs regarding WebGazer.js and what scripts order should be, so I checked the code example you provided. And I noticed that scripts there are being imported differently compared to yours.

So, in `_Layout.cshtml` try to put these at the bottom of the `body` tag like this:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/js/webgazer.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/calibration.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/precision_calculation.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/precision_store_points.js"></script>

@*<script src="~/js/gaze.js"></script>*@

<script src="~/js/resize_canvas.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You may notice that `~/js/gaze.js` is commented. Unfortunately, I could not find this script in the GitHub repository you provided, but it appears to be according to your code.

At this moment we are almost done. If you try to run the application, you will get errors in the browser's Dev Tools Console saying that `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext') at ClearCanvas (calibration.js:10:10)`. To solve this issue, you have to provide a `canvas` element in the HTML like this:

```
@page "/Calibration"

@inject IJSRuntime JS

<h1>Calibration</h1>

------------------------------------RIGHT HERE-----------------------------------
<canvas id="plotting_canvas" width="500" height="500" style="cursor:crosshair;"></canvas>
------------------------------------RIGHT HERE-----------------------------------

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">

    <li id="Accuracy"><a>Not yet Calibrated</a></li>

    <li> <button @onclick="CalibrateWebgazer">Calibrate WebGazer</button></li>

</ul>


<div class="calibrationDiv">
    <button class="Calibration" id="Pt1"></button>
    <button class="Calibration" id="Pt2"></button>
    <button class="Calibration" id="Pt3"></button>
    <button class="Calibration" id="Pt4"></button>
    <button class="Calibration" id="Pt5"></button>
    <button class="Calibration" id="Pt6"></button>
    <button class="Calibration" id="Pt7"></button>
    <button class="Calibration" id="Pt8"></button>
    <button class="Calibration" id="Pt9"></button>

</div>

@code { . . . }
```

I also found it in the example code you provided. It should work!